# How can I make a cross-domain request from my reactjs component?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, axios

I have a reactjs component and in one of the methods I would like to make an ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         crossDomain: true,
         url:'http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1',
         success: (res) => {},
         error: (fail) => {}
      })
```

When I load the component the request fails to load with an error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

Is it possible to fix this issue or should I get a different approach?

Comment: `http` to `https` but look like that site not support `SSL`  it up to that website, it should allow cross-domain and enable SSL for api thing

Comment: cant be fixed on client...the side server need to enable CORS

Comment: Change the api endpoint to `https://api.openweathermap.org/...`. It should enable CORS by default.

Comment: request failed......

Answer (score -1):

*to make cross domain request you should use either jsonp or reversy proxy*

```
    $.ajax({
    url:"http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1",
    type:"GET",
    jsonpCallback: "getStatus",
    dataType: "jsonp",

});
function getStatus(response)
{
    console.log(response);
}
```

Comment: `Refused to execute script from ... because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`